# The repetitive background image leaves a line on the ios phone, how to solve this

Tags: css, ios, react-native

[image]

The resulting line is as shown above.

```
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Comment: A quick and dirty solution but which tends to be OK visually may be to put a background-color on in that dark color.

If there is more to it than that please put a runnable snippet in your question, including a version of the background image that we can see.

Comment: containerProps: {
    backgroundSize: '100%',
    url: `${THEME_PATH}/four/bg.svg`,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    headerImageProps: {
      url: `${THEME_PATH}/four/header.svg`,
      m: { base: '-17vw 0 -29.5vw 0', sm: '-130px 0 -200px 0' },
    },
    footerImageProps: {
      url: `${THEME_PATH}/four/footer.svg`,
      m: { base: '-25vw 0 0 0', sm: '-200px 0 0 0' },
    },
  },

I did what you said but it didn't work css code is like this